# Sending images in email with PHP / CakePHP

Tags: php, html, email, cakephp, swiftmailer

This is a two parter. First of all, I've seen mixed opinions on embedding images vs using a link. I've seen both sides pointing fingers at the other. Is there a general consensus as to which tends to be stopped less by spam filters? Should I forgo embedding images and just use links?

Now for my programming issues. I'm trying to embed images in an email using SwiftMailer with CakePHP 2.3.8 being sent from localhost, however they're not displaying. The image is attached to the email and I can download it, but it's not actually showing in the email. I followed [these steps](http://bakery.cakephp.org/users/view/imatt) to embed images with the SwiftMailer component/plugin.

So, on the email I checked the source of the image and it appears like this

```
<img src="http://img/cid%3A555128d0923bccc63d63c1d60eef1a51%40localhost" alt="">
```

On the layout itself (contents of the email), I display the image like so

```
echo $this->Html->image($cid['image_name']);
```

If I just echo the image name (without the image tag) it shows the cid which was created for this image. When opening this up with the default mail client on OSX other images are shown.

Comment: Have you tried hosting the image somewhere and use it in `src`

Comment: @blo did you actually read my post?